# How to empty select box in ajax call onchange another select box with multiselect plugin of jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, append, jquery-ui-multiselect

> I am having 2 dependent dropdowns. Second one is depend on first
>   dropdown. I am using onchange event to get data in second dropdown
>   with ajax call.

below is my 2 dropdowns and ajax call :

first select box:

```
<select name="cust_type" id="cust_type"  class="cust_type" 
    onchange="getCustomersByType(this.value);" > 
    <?php echo $customer_type;?>
</select>
```

Second select box:

```
<select  name="CompanyName[]" id="CompanyName" multiple  class="customer_name" > 
</select>
```

ajax call :

```
function getCustomersByType(value)
        {
            var getCust = $('#cust_type').val();

            var customer_type = value;
                $.ajax({
                method: "GET",
                dataType: 'json',
                url:"include/ajax_files/bank_book/getdata.php?getCust="+getCust,
                    success:function(data)
                        {
                            $('#CompanyName').empty();
                            $.each(data, function(index, value) 
                                {
                                    $("#CompanyName").append('<option value="' + value.CUSTOMER_ID + '"'  +
                                    '>' + value.CUSTOMER_NAME+ '</option>');
                                    $('#CompanyName').multiselect('rebuild');
                                });
                        } 
                });


        };
```

my data is proper. I am able to change my second dropdown with change on first. 
But when i am using multiselect plugin with checkbox for multiselect second dropdown failed to change data.

Below is code for multiselect :

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#CompanyName').multiselect({
        columns: 1,
        placeholder: 'Select Com',
        search: true,
        selectGroup: true,
        selectAll: true,
        maxPlaceholderOpts: 0,
    });
 });
```

please help me with this to empty select onchange first dropdown and show data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `reload` method to display the new options after populating.

```
$('#CompanyName').multiSelect('reload');
```

Comment: i tried with this still its not working. i replace this line with `$('#CompanyName').multiselect('rebuild');`

Comment: which jquery multiselect plugin you are using?

Comment: multiselect plugin

Comment: There are many multiselect plugin, can you please point to the exact plugin you are using.

Comment: @Source: https://github.com/nobleclem/jQuery-MultiSelect this is the source i have with me only

Comment: i tried with this too. its not working. nothing happens. do you have any other well plugin

Comment: Try using select2 plugin.